# Target Two Elements For replaceWith()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to replace two server side generated images with the same text character. Is it possible to target both elements in the same line of jQuery, like so:

```
$('img.first','img.firstDisabled').replaceWith('&laquo;');
```

I've tried this in my code and it doesn't seem to work, so at this point I'm just wondering whether it's possible and I've been doing it wrong, or if I'm just barking up the wrong tree altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comma needs to be within a single selector string, not separating two strings:

```
$('img.first, img.firstDisabled').replaceWith('&laquo;');
```

Splitting it into two selector strings means finding selector1 within the context of selector2, which of course doesn't make sense in the context of your question since you can't find an `img` within an `img`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('img.first, img.firstDisabled').replaceWith('&laquo;');`

See [Jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) about multiple selectors.